# different Users have Different rights on a computers?

Tags: active-directory

In a domain, i want to when a user login in a system have the permissions of Administrators and another Users when loginig have a permissions of just Users? I know this is possible with GPOs but i dont know how?
please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily grant the user permissions on the local computer using the local users control panel item, or the local users and groups MMC snapin.  Simply add the domain user to the administrators local group to grant them admin rights.  They will generally have user rights by default.  You can also add domain groups to local groups.

You don't need to use a GPO for that.  However, if you want to do this for all the computers in a domain without making the users to have admin rights domain admins, you can use a GPO to do the local group addition.  There is a guide with pictures here: http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/01/how-to-use-group-policy-preferences-to-secure-local-administrator-groups/

In short, the process is similar to how you would do it on one: create a GPO and set up a rule to add the user or group to the administrators group on the target computer.  This setting is within computer configuration, in the control panel settings in preferences.  Then, apply the GPO to an OU in AD containing all the computer objects you want to grant local admin rights on.

Comment: Thank you for your rapid replying, but the above link was for restricting local administrators could'nt add the other user as a another administrator, indeed blocking members tab. In my scenario i need that a when a local administrator login to system have full rights of administrators for example installing softwares,... and another users only have a permissions of a guest users.

Comment: The GPO can both clean out the group (the options to delete all member users and groups), and add people to it.  Click the add button and add someone (you'll have to qualify the account name with the domain, as in the screenshots).  Then, make sure the GPO applies to the PC you are testing on, do a `gpupdate` on it, and all should be as you expect.